# Navigate from UIViewController to UITabbarController

Tags: ios

I have `UIViewController` as a `rootViewController` and I want to navigate from `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController` after click button1.

[image: navigate to tab1 after click on button1. ignore other button]

navigate to tab1 after click on button1. ignore other button

here is my IBAction method for btn1

```
- (IBAction)btn1Click:(id)sender {


 }
```

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to give `storyboardID` to UITabBarController using storyboard, such as `tabVC`. After that write below code to open the `UITabBarController` as model segue.

```
-(IBAction)btn1Click:(id)sender {
     UITabbarController *tabVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabVC"];
     [self presentViewController:tabVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is the exception? did you set the `storyboardID` for `UITabBarController `?

Comment: sorry yogesh exception is for other reason. now I got warning.   Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController: 0x7aedddc0> on <ViewController: 0x7c162810> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @stack Can you post the code? Because I am thinking you are opening the `UITabBarController` by push seque and may be your `UIViewController` is not embedded in `UINavigationController` it will crash the app.